# Increase Integer in SimpleXML XPath variable doesn't work

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm creating a PDF-View-Counter.

Now I'm stuck at changing the "view" value from the XML. When I'm trying to sum the variable (`$VAR++`), it doesn't work. What should I do?

```
<?php

$datei = "pdf.pdf";

$xmldb = "db.xml";

$id = md5($datei);

$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmldb);

$views = $xml->xpath('/data/count[@id="'.$id.'"]/views');

$num = $views[0][0];

$num++;

echo $num; // it doesn't work
```

XML-Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <count id="883c7046854e04138c55680ffde90a61">
        <filename>s</filename>
        <views>1</views>
        <lastview>f</lastview>
    </count>
</data>
```

Comment: it doesn't work: not a good way to ask that way alone: tell what you expected (and perhaps why) and tell what happens instead. Then it's clear what you mean when you write "it doesn't work". Otherwise it's not clear, someone reading your question needs to guess right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you must cast the resulting object into integer.

As far as I know `SimpleXML->xpath()` always returns an array with zero or more **SimpleXMLElement**  Objects.

```
$num = (int) $views[0];
$num++;
```

Comment: Alternative: Assign the integer value as new element text: `$num = $views[0][0]; $num[0] = 1 + $num;`. The important part is here that `++` (increment operator) does *not* work with objects that have `__toString()` (like **SimpleXMLElement**).